# How to read gibberish .data file from APK

Tags: apk, decode

I have a .data file given to me that I am suppose to read. I know that .data files can be opened with a text editor, and that was the first thing I did. The result from opening the .data file was gibberish:

```
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
```

I am not sure what to do with this .data file and what I can do to get the readable file.

Edit: This is my first post in stack overflow, hopefully I followed guidelines and please let me know if I should categorize this question with a different tag. Thanks!

Comment: that looks like base64 encoded binary data

Comment: I decoded using base64, and the output is still gibberish. It works when the output is in hexadecimal, but not in text. What steps should I take next?

Comment: As I said, it's binary data and that doesn't look nice when you try to read it as text, but it's not supposed to be read as text.  The thing is, it's usually hard to figure out what kind of data is stored in a data file and it could even be encrypted. And without any context (the only context you gave is: data file in an APK) it's even harder to figure out. Ask the developer.

Comment: This is a file from an android game that I opened in an emulator. The file name is called lottery_win_number.data and it should contain the winning number from a past event. There are many other .data files stored in the folder, but I picked this one for simplicity since I could always check for the correct answer after. All the other .data files in the folders share the same encoding.